# Angular with ngrx and typescript problems with effects

Tags: typescript, rxjs, ngrx

I'm having some issues using ngrx, i get an error when trying to do a simple effect. The error i get is Argument of type '`MonoTypeOperatorFunction<LoadContainerAction>`' is not assignable to parameter of type '`OperatorFunction<Action, Action>`' on the line for startWith.

```
@Injectable()
export class Effects {
    @Effect()
    loadCollection$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$
        .pipe(
            ofType(ActionTypes.LOAD_CONTAINER),
            startWith(new LoadContainerAction()),
            switchMap(() =>
                this.apiService.get<Container[]>("books")
                    .then(items => new LoadContainerSuccessAction(items))
                    .catch(error => of(new LoadContainerFailAction(error)))
            )
        );

    constructor(private actions$: Actions, private apiService: ApiService) { }
}
```

This is how ActionTypes and LoadContainerAction looks like:

```
export enum ActionTypes {
    LOAD_CONTAINER = "[container] load",
    LOAD_CONTAINER_SUCCESS = "[container] load success",
    LOAD_CONTAINER_FAILURE = "[container] load fail",
}

export class LoadContainerAction implements Action {
    readonly type = ActionTypes.LOAD_CONTAINER;
}
```

These are my (related) imports:

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { Action } from "@ngrx/store";
import { Effect, Actions, ofType } from "@ngrx/effects";
import { Observable, of } from "rxjs";
import { startWith, switchMap } from "rxjs/operators";
```

I am using rxjs: 6.1.0 and ngrx: 6.0.0-beta.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 ofType<LoadContainerAction>(ActionTypes.LOAD_CONTAINER),
```

Seem to have solved it instead of simply `ofType(...)`